# get xautolock status

Tags: xorg, screen-lock

I'm currently using [xautolock](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xautolock) to automatically lock my screen with [slock](http://tools.suckless.org/slock/). However, when I'm watching a movie, I certainly *don't* want my screen to go black suddenly. I read the manpage and saw that `xautolock -toggle` bound to a keyboard shortcut ought to give me control over the whole thing.

**But, I want to see the current status.** Or I will get confused. Does anyone know a way to find the xautolock status, or should I do something like make a file containing the current status and use -enable / -disable, checking the file, and `notify-send`ing something?

Comment: I was searching for a way to do this once for debugging a script, but never found out how. I suspect it's not possible. If you are going to make a file containing the current status, it's probably easier (and more failsafe) to just `pkill xautolock`, and `pgrep xautolock` to test if it's running.

Comment: Another potential solution would be to use `caffeine`, but [unfortunately](https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/1296666) it doesn't support `xautolock`.

Comment: @Sparhawk Yes, I still use caffeine on my desktop which is running cinnamon and xscreensaver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the functionality built into most media players to manage this; it works efectively with `xautolock` and it's lockers.

[mpv](http://mpv.io/) and [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) both have a screensaver options:

```
--stop-screensaver, --no-stop-screensaver
Turns off the screensaver (or screen blanker and similar mechanisms) at startup and turns it
on  again  on  exit  (default: yes). The screensaver is always re-enabled when the player
is paused.

This  is  not  supported on all video outputs or platforms. Sometimes it is implemented,
but does not work (happens often on GNOME). You might be able to to work this around using
--heartbeat-cmd instead.
```

You can enable this fucntionality by including the line in your `~/.mpv/config`:

```
stop-screensaver=yes
```

and enjoy uninterrupted playback of your videos.

If you are using a media player that doesn't have this basic functionality, you can use a simple wrapper to acheive the same effect:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# wrapper to prevent screen blanking when files are played from ~/Videos

usage() {
    printf "%s\n" "Usage: ${0##*/} /path/to/file"
    exit 1
}

case $# in
    1)  if [[ $1 =~ Videos ]]; then
            xset dpms 0 0 0
            xautolock -disable
            vlc "$1"
            xautolock -enable
            xset dpms 900 900 900
        else
            usage
        fi
        ;;
    *) usage
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, and decided to make a list of "blocking" applications for slock instead. But thanks. Especially for mplayer option. I assume gnome-mplayer also supports it?

Comment: @MadTux I would imagine so: check the manual to confirm, I'm not sure how gnome-mplayer differs from mplayer itself.

Comment: Couldn't find it in the man page, and trying it out gave me an error :/ That's odd. Ah well, your answer (and my solution) solve it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

A quick check of the [source code](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/X11/screensavers/) of the current version, `xautolock 2.2`, shows that it doesn't support this feature, although it wouldn't be too hard to implement it yourself if you know a little bit about `C` and how to write `X` programs.

The reason is probably this: whenever you want to know the status of `xautolock`, you also know what status you would like it to be in. So, simply issue `xautolock -disable` if you want it to be off, and `xautolock -enable` in the contrary case. Note that all your other `xautolock` settings will not be affected by doing this.

Keeping track of the status yourself the way you suggest is also possible, but probably somewhat unreliable and error-prone.

Comment: I just made a script with `pgrep mplayer || slock` and told` xautolock to use that. Maybe I'll bind separate keyboard shortcuts to -disable and -enable ...

Comment: it's a very basic requirement and there's really no excuse not to include it in `xautolock`...

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do just what OP asked and it's all contained in my i3 configuration, bound to a shortcut (see below). So I lock my screen with Mod+o and I toggle automatic screen locking with Mod+Shift+o where notification appears that tells me either "LOCK on" or "LOCK OFF", depending on xautolock's "status". I made use of `xautlock -exit` to figure out whether or not it's running without having to manage the status in an extra file.

The script that takes care of toggled status just by itself looks like this

```
if xautolock -exit
    then (notify-send -u normal -t 100 -- 'LOCK OFF') 2> /dev/null
    else
        notify-send -u normal -t 100 -- 'LOCK on'
        xautolock -time 2 -locker 'slock' -notify 10 -notifier "notify-send -u normal -t 100 -- 'LOCKING screen ...'"
fi
```

Depending on where you call that script, you have to make sure `xautolock -time ...` runs in the background (e.g. by adding `&`).

From my `.i3/config` file:

```
exec --no-startup-id xautolock -time 2 -locker 'slock' -notify 10 -notifier "notify-send -u normal -t 10000 -- 'LOCKING screen'"

bindsym $mod+o exec --no-startup-id xautolock -locknow
bindsym $mod+Shift+o exec --no-startup-id "if xautolock -exit; then (notify-send -u normal -t 100 -- 'LOCK OFF') 2> /dev/null; else notify-send -u normal -t 100 -- 'LOCK on'; xautolock -time 2 -locker 'slock' -notify 10 -notifier \\"notify-send -u normal -t 100 -- 'LOCKING screen ...'\\"; fi"
```